# how to add timeout of connection to ffmpeg command when retriving rtsp?

Tags: ffmpeg

I used the following command to transfer a rtsp stream to a .mp4 file:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -timeout 5000000 -i "rtsp://zigong.stream.xl02.cn:557/HongTranSvr?DevId=1b038d27-858c-46a1-b803-a2984af343df&Session=1b038d27-858c-46a1-b803-a2984af343df"  -vcodec copy -t 5 -y "capture.mp4"
```

The result is as below:

```
[rtsp @ 0x5655577ccc00] Unable to open RTSP for listening
rtsp://zigong.stream.xl02.cn:557/HongTranSvr?DevId=1b038d27-858c-46a1-b803-a2984af343df&Session=1b038d27-858c-46a1-b803-a2984af343df: Cannot assign requested address
```

But it worded fine if I delete the timeout option...
the ffmpeg version is:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.12-1~deb9u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to update FFmpeg version and replace `-timeout` into `-stimeout`.

This issue was fixed a few months ago. [[ref](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2294)]